# What supports Excel better ? ( VB.net or C#.net ?? )

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, ms-office, export-to-excel

I need to implement reporting.. with Excel sheets and need a lot of heavy excel workings..
So..

I have two options.. 
C#.net or VB.net !!

What would be more closer to EXCEL ?
What would provide me more excel api's and more control ?

Please Help !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both C# and VB.NET allow you to write code that targets .NET equally well.  You can use either language to work with the Excel interop libraries.  There really is no advantage to one language over the other for working with Excel.

Comment: Great.. some says... VB.Net so.. I will stick with VB.net !

Comment: Of course in case of C# version below 4.0 you must be prepared for using "Missing.Value" a lot. Hardly a good selling point.

Answer (score 3):

C# and vb.net are both .net languages so they would give you equal access to any excel/office APIs since anything that can be linked to C# also could be linked to vb.net

vb is closer to thr vba language used in excel macros, but personally I would always prefer C#. If you are used to vba vb.net would probably be the right choice for you since you then know the syntax.